# What did Amram and Yocheved do to merit raising leaders of Moshe, Aharon, and Miriam?

Tags: sources-mekorot, moshe-rabbeinu, children-parenting, miriam, aharon

Although Amram and Yocheved were influential leaders in their own right (seen in [Sotah 12a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.12a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) where Klal Yisroel followed their lead in divorcing from their spouses), do any Chazal or Torah commentators explain what Amram and Yocheved did as parents to merit raising Moshe, Aharon, and Miriam?

Comment: The title implies the only way to have great children is to do something special to earn it. Why do you assume that to be the case?

Comment: @jay my answer below addresses that point to some degree.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, there is a fascinating philosophical point that relates to this question. Maharal ([Gur Aryeh to Shemot 1:15](https://rashi.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/1.15#e0nf)) points out that neither Yocheved, nor Amram's names were mentioned prior to Moshe's birth because Moshe was destined for this role from when G-d created the world. Had their names been mentioned, argues Maharal, it might cause people to think that Moshe was as great as he was due to his parents. Maharal argues that no matter who would have given birth to Moshe, he would have played the same role:

> ואם תאמר למה לא הזכיר את שם יוכבד ושם מרים בפירוש, ויראה שאין הכתוב מזכיר שם יוכבד ומרים ואהרן עד אחר לידת משה (להלן ב, א), שהרי בפרשה שאחריה כתיב (להלן ב, א) ״וילך איש מבית לוי ויקח את בת לוי״ - לא רצה להזכיר שם האב ושם האם של משה עד לידת משה, לומר לך כי משה היה מתוקן לגאולה מו׳ ימי בראשית, ומאחר שמשה מתוקן לגאולה מששת ימי בראשית - לא היו אבותיו עיקר אצלו, ואילו נתן שם לאביו קודם לידת משה היה משמעות הענין שהעיקר היה האב, ובשביל עצמו ושמו המיוחד לו נתן לו הקב״ה משה, כמו כל אב שהוא בפרט סבה לבן, לכך לא הזכיר שמו, כי אצל לידת משה לא היה האב סבה מיוחדת רק כאשר הוא כסדר עולם וכמנהג שכל אדם מוליד בן, אבל סבה פרטית לא היה כאן. וכל שאר בנים - אם לא היה זה האב לא בא הבן לעולם, וזה אינו במשה, כי אף שהיה עמרם מוכן יותר למשה, על כל פנים מוכרח משה לבא לעולם, ולפיכך אינו מזכיר שם הפרטי קודם לידת משה, שלא תאמר כי נולד מעמרם בפרט, ואם לא היה עמרם לא היה נולד משה, שזה אינו, רק הוא כמו שאר אדם, ואם לא היה עמרם היה אחר, כי משה מתוקן מששת ימי בראשית. והבן עוד יותר מזה כי הוא ענין נפלא. ובספר גבורות ה׳ (פט״ז) הארכנו גם בזה, ודבר זה נכון:

Nevertheless, the OP's question was what they did to merit having such righteous children. One answer to this question can be found in the commentary of the Maharzu (Rabbi Zev Wolf Einhorn; a particularly comical error on his [biographical entry on Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/person/Zev%20Wolf%20Einhorn) lists him as having lived for close to 400 years, which is ironic, since we are citing his comments about Yocheved, but I digress). Midrash Rabbah Bamidbar 3:6 ([link](https://www.sefaria.org/Bamidbar_Rabbah.3?lang=bi)) states:

> דָּבָר אַחֵר, אֱלֹהִים מוֹשִׁיב יְחִידִים, מִי הָיָה זֶה עַמְרָם וְיוֹכֶבֶד, בִּזְכוּת לְהוֹצִיא אֲסִירִים בַּכּוֹשָׁרוֹת, אֵלּוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל, שֶׁהָיוּ מְשֻׁעְבָּדִים בְּמִצְרַיִם. מֶה עָשָׂה הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא זִוֵּג יוֹכֶבֶד לְעַמְרָם בִּכְדֵי שֶׁיַּעֲמֹד מֵהֶם גּוֹאֵל וְיִגְאַל יִשְׂרָאֵל

Thus, this Midrash claims that they merited to be paired together with each other because they were "Yechidim". Maharzu (in his commentary there; [link](https://www.sefaria.org/Perush_Maharzu_on_Bamidbar_Rabbah.3.6.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) explains that this word implies greatness, and finds traits of Amaram's and Yocheved's to match it:

> יחידים לשון גדולה כנ"ל על שעמרם שהיה גדול הדור כמ"ש שמ"ר פר"א סי' כ"ב ויוכבד יחידה בדורה בת לוי שעל ידי זה מוציא אסירים:

> "Yechidim" is language of greatness, as it was mentioned earlier about Amram, that he was the "Gadol Hador" (Shemot Rabbah 1:22) and Yocheved was unique in her generation as the daughter of Levi, and through this, they merited to take out the captives...

Additionally, the Talmud in Sotah (11b, Davidson Edition translation; [link](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.11b.22?lang=bi)) appears to write explicitly that Yocheved (identified by the Talmud there as one of the midwives) merited Aharon and Moshe for her role in saving Jewish children:

> (שמות א, כא) ויהי כי יראו המילדות את האלהים ויעש להם בתים רב ושמואל חד אמר בתי כהונה ולויה וחד אמר בתי מלכות **מ"ד בתי כהונה ולויה אהרן ומשה** ומ"ד בתי מלכות דוד נמי ממרים קאתי דכתיב (דברי הימים א ב, יט) ותמת עזובה (אשת כלב) ויקח לו כלב את אפרת ותלד לו את חור וכתיב (שמואל א יז, יב) ודוד בן איש אפרתי וגו'

> The verse relates the midwives’ reward: “And it came to pass, because the midwives feared God, that He made them houses” (Exodus 1:21). Rav and Shmuel disagree as to the precise interpretation of these houses: One says that God made the houses of the priesthood and the Levites descend from the midwives, and one says that God made the houses of royalty descend from them. **The one who says that it is referring to the houses of the priesthood and the Levites is referring to Aaron and Moses, who were sons of Jochebed.** And the one who says that it is referring to houses of royalty is referring to David, who also comes from Miriam, as it is written: “And Azubah,” the wife of Caleb, “died, and Caleb took to him Ephrath, who bore him Hur” (I Chronicles 2:19) and, as will be explained further, Ephrath is Miriam. And it is written: “David was the son of that Ephrathite of Bethlehem in Judah” (I Samuel 17:12). Therefore, he was a descendant of Miriam.

Edit: This addition was prompted by Dov's answer - as per the verse that the Talmud cites there, it was Yocheved's fear of G-d that was rewarded by Hashem according to the Talmud, which is not necessarily the same as her saving Jewish children.

Answer (score 3):

It writes in [Shemos Rabbah 1:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.1.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> לְפִי שֶׁיָּרְאָה יוֹכֶבֶד מִפְּנֵי הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא, הֶעֱמִיד מִמֶּנָּה משֶׁה
>
> Because Yocheved feared Hashem, he brought forth Moshe from her.

In addition, the Gemara in [Shabbos 55b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.55b.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) tells us that Amram never sinned in his lifetime (he died only due to the counsel of the snake). The Maharal in [Chiddushei Aggados](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14194&st=&pgnum=60&hilite=) (2nd paragraph) on this Gemara in Shabbos writes:

> מה שהיה עמרם אבי משה, אשר היה משה שקול נגד כל ישראל, לא יצה למשה לפעל רק על ידי מי שהוא ישר
>
> How was Amram the father of Moshe who was equal to all of Israel, Moshe would not have come out in actuality unless from someone who was upright...

So the Maharal says expressly that Amram had to have been incredibly righteous and upright otherwise he would never have never been zoche to have such a child like Moshe. It was is perfect character that gave rise to such a child.

Comment: I like the addition

Comment: Many thanks! :-)